# Failed to restart sshd.service

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I try to run the command `sudo systemctl status sshd`. However, I get the message below.

> Failed to restart sshd.service: Interactive authentication required.
> See system logs and 'systemctl status sshd.service' for details.

This is my `etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

```
 Port22 PermitRootLogin yes
 PubkeyAuthentication No
 PasswordAuthentication yes 
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
 X11Forwarding yes 
 PrintMotd no 
 UseDNS yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you really mean `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?  The server config is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

What happens if you try to start it with

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

Comment: I can restart using this command 'sudo systemctl restart ssh'